# Connection between two notions of undecidability

Tags: logic, decision-theory

As far as I understand, there are two common notions of "undecidability" that I will call

- "Mathematical undecidability":="the statement can neither be proved nor disproved from the axioms", equivalently, it is true in some model and false in some other model, and
- "Algorithmic undecidability":="there is no algorithm that, for a given input, corretly decides yes/no". More formally, the possible inputs are ordered and the set of indices of true statements is not a [recursive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set).

If I'm (at least partially) right in the above, I would like to understand the link between those two notions. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem#Examples_of_undecidable_statements), I read

> The connection between these two is that if a decision problem is
>   undecidable (in the recursion theoretical sense) then there is no
>   consistent, effective formal system which proves for every question A
>   in the problem either "the answer to A is yes" or "the answer to A is
>   no".

This is quite vaguely formulated.

**Question:**

> Is it true that for every algorithmically undecidable problem, for
>   some particular instance of the input, the statement is mathematically
>   undecidable (using Peano arithmetic)?

Comment: You have to distinguish between "the statement is undecideable" and "the statement is not decideable for every input".  Goldbach's conjecture could be undecideable, but for a given input, it is decideable.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's clear. But I'm interested in (algorithmically) undecidable problems. If you have one -- for example, solvability of integral polynomial equations -- does it imply that in some instance (solvability of some particular polynomial equation, e.g.) it is independent of Peano axioms?

Comment: Very interesting: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130789/are-the-two-meanings-of-undecidable-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a problem is ALGORITHMICALLY undecideable (no algorithm can decide the statement for every input) , then it is undecideable in any sufficiently strong formal system. Otherwise you could program the rules of the formal system and decide the problem.

"Sufficiently strong" means : The representation theorem holds. This is already true for the peano axioms. So, there must be an instance for which PA can neither proof that it is true nor that it is false.

The representation theorem states that every computable function can be formalized in the system.

Comment: What is representation theorem?

Comment: My question is, whether some instance of the input is independent from Peano axioms. In simpler words: does there exists a polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients such that the satisfiability of $P=0$ is neither provable nor refutable from Peano axioms?

Comment: Yes, there exist polynomials without a solution, for which PA cannot prove that there is no solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Could you give me a reference please?

Comment: If you are content with a german site : Joerg Resag - Grenzen der Berechenbarkeit

Comment: @Peter That's ok, thanks. Don't you want to change "...then it is undecidable in any..." to "...then for some input it is undecidable in any..."? It would be clearer to me.

Comment: This formulation is false. ZFC is stronger than PA, so there are equations decideable in ZFC, but not in PA. We first have to fix the formal system, and then we can claim that there must be an undecideable input within the given formal system. If we fix the input, it will not be undecideable in every formal system.

Comment: @Peter I think that you answered my question, but maybe it would be better if you included some of these remarks into the answer. I hope I understand you correctly now: if you first fix the system (let's say, Peano), then you can find some (mathematically) undecidable problem instance for some input.

Comment: Yes, for every formal system you can find an input, such that the system cannot decide it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer which is a bit closer to the quote from Wikipedia. If you have some property $\phi(n)$ in the language of PA and if, for every natural number constant $\overline{n}$, either PA proves $\phi(\overline{n})$ or PA disproves $\phi(\overline{n})$, then $\phi(n)$ is algorithmically decidable: given an input $\overline{n}$, enumerate proofs in PA until you find one that either proves $\phi(\overline{n})$ or disproves it. This is guaranteed to terminate by our assumption on $\phi$ and when it terminates we know whether $\phi(\overline{n})$ is true or not (because PA is sound).